# Using Multi-threading on a library management system

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm working on a `library management system` in Java.

Now I finished it, but I don't use and thread and multi-hreading concepts on it.

Where should I use multi-threading on this particular program?

My program has 2 mode for login:

1. administration
2. User

In administration mode, the add/remove/change and reporting from books and users is doable.

In user mode, user can see all books and they borrowed status and can select a book and borrow its favorite book if it is not borrowed.

Where should i use it?

Comment: If you finished it without any multithreading, and it works, you don't need any multithreading.

Comment: If it is a desktop application and your operations are executed on UI thread then you have a place for changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use multi-threading if you don't need it. As you write you are finished with your application. If it works as needed and your user can find and borrow books there is no need to add multi-threading.